# Ожидание получения данных в вызванной функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

Из функции вызываю другую функцию, в которой отображаю [кастомный prompt](http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html#prompt-with-select). Как дождаться получения ответа от второй функции?

```
jQuery('#button').on('click', '.test', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    let choice=choice();
    console.log(choice); //дождаться ответа от функции choice();
}

function choice() {
    bootbox.prompt({
        title: "This is a prompt with select!",
        inputType: 'select',
        inputOptions: [
            {
                text: 'Choose one...',
                value: '',
            },
            {
                text: 'Choice One',
                value: '1',
            },
            {
                text: 'Choice Two',
                value: '2',
            },
            {
                text: 'Choice Three',
                value: '3',
            }
        ],
        callback: function (result) {
            if(result) {
                return result; //дождаться получения ответа
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ну у вас же есть коллбэк, в нем и должен быть результат выполнения, не дожидайтесь ничего, обрабатывайте результат в коллбэке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если принципиально нужно получить результат внутри jQuery('#button').on(), можно сделать так:

```
jQuery('#button').on('click', '.test', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    choice(function(result) {
        console.log(result); //дождаться ответа от функции choice();
    });
}

function choice(cb) {
    bootbox.prompt({
        title: "This is a prompt with select!",
        inputType: 'select',
        inputOptions: [
            {
                text: 'Choose one...',
                value: '',
            },
            {
                text: 'Choice One',
                value: '1',
            },
            {
                text: 'Choice Two',
                value: '2',
            },
            {
                text: 'Choice Three',
                value: '3',
            }
        ],
        callback: cb
    });
}
```

Замечу, что так, как вы хотели сделать, не получится - для этого пришлось бы останавливать выполнение скрипта. Так работает обычный window.confirm(), но не кастомные prompt'ы и, как правило, не любой другой пользовательский код.